# Micronaut static videos not loading

Tags: micronaut

I am new to Micronaut, so this might not be the best phrased question.  Okay, with the humble pie out of the way...

I have a small MVC app written in Java with a series of static assets in addition to the controllers and services.  These are in src/main/resources/public with various subdirectories (CSS, JS, videos, etc.).  My application.yml has:

```
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        paths: 'classpath:public'
```

Everything *except* the videos are displaying fine on my index.html page.  CSS, Javascript, images, they all load fine.  The videos *appear* to load fine (i.e., the browser shows video controls when I right click in those areas of the page), but the videos themselves do not play and appear blank.  When checking the developer console, all the vidoes, regardless of size are returned with a 200 response code and exactly 251 bytes.

The setup for static assets seems straightforward and simple.  However, the videos are not loading.  Is there a trick to have Bitnami load them, like playing with the Netty settings?  Or is it recommended to front Micronaut with Apache and serve more resource intensive assets like videos from there?

My thanks!
Saish